# How to start app from first when home button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application when i click home button and when again when i open the app it should come from first.I am having splash screen as my first activity.when i open the app,the app should start from  splash screen.

```
         @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

      if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
       {
        Log.i("Home Button","Clicked");


        onPause();
       }

   return false;



      }
    protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause(); 
        Intent i=new Intent(H2.this,HomeexampleActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // Start your first Activity as you would normally do

    }
```

I tried in this way by overriding on pause method but it is not working.please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: Inside `onPause()`, `super.onPause()` should be the first statement.

Comment: i tried in that way also but i didnt get

Comment: That was not a solution to your problem. That is how it should be. Keep it that way.

Comment: try finishing this current activty as    if(!isFinishing()&&<your_otehr_bolelan_indefify_home_presse>){
      finish();
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 Boolean hasGone = false;
  @Override
 void onResume() {
  super.onResume();  
  if(hasGone){    
      Intent intent = new Intent(H2.this, HomeexampleActivity.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
 }

 @Override
 void onPause() {
     super.onPause(); 
     hasGone = true;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your resopnse it is working fine for home button but if i click escape it is not going to previous page instead it is coming from first page that is splash screen in my application.

Comment: @user1083266: I had test my code, and it worked fine when I click back key (like escape). Have you removed onKeyDown( that call onPause()) from above code yet?

Comment: Very strange, because I tested this code. when you in H2 activity, press back it go to HomeexampleActivity? can you update the order called activity?

Comment: Splashscree->homeactivity->h1->h2 this is my order of clases

Comment: @user1083266: I don' know where is your problem because this code worked on my emulator. Maybe you should update full source code of H2 activity in your question, then I may help.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing this line in your each activity tag in Manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` before `startActivity(i);`

Comment: if i use on pause method am having on button on click those actions are not working

Comment: i tried using on stop also but home button is working like back button please suggest me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should have that code in `onResume()` not in `onPause()`. Because, when you click on your Home button, `onPause()` is called. But when you resume your application, `onResume()` is called. Hence, if you want to redirect your application to start from the beginning again, start your first `Activity` in `onResume()` method in all your `Activity` classes.

Keep in mind, that `onResume()` is also called once immediately after `onCreate()`, so keep a `flag` value to check whether your `onResume()` is called after `onCreate()` or is it called when your application is resuming.

Comment: so no need of on pause method

Comment: I believe no. Because, as I said, `onPause()` is called when you pause your `Activity`. But what you want to do is something that has to be done when you resume your `Activity`. Hence, `onResume()` is the way to go.

Comment: i am having button on click it not going to next page

Comment: Did you do the `flag` check I told you to? remember, `onResume()` is also called after `onCreate()`. Probably why you are having trouble I guess.

Comment: in my application i am having three activities home1,h1,h2.the button which is in home1 when i click it should go to h1 but due to on resume it is not going to h1

Comment: Exactly. I told you to keep a `flag` variable to check for it. Your `onResume()` is called after `onCreate()`, so keep a check for it.

Comment: Remember, `onCreate()` is called when the `Activity` is created. `onResume()` will be called once after it. So it's like, you need to avoid the first call to `onResume()`, design your flag that way. If problem persists,let me know.